# Appropriate way to deal with Personality Disorder in loved one?

Tags: mental-health

Are there any preferred or recommended ways to intervene when a loved one appears to be suffering from a [Dramatic Personality Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_B_personality_disorders), specifically [Narcissistic Personality Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder) and [Borderline Personality Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderline_personality_disorder)?

Rather than strategies for "dealing with it", how should one help another seek help/treatment without feeding a [victim mentality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_mentality)?